# deleting children records in a hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember 1.4 with EmberData beta 7.

When a parent record is deleted, the children records don't get automatically deleted from store.  So I'm trying to loop through to delete the children before deleting the parent.

I tried this:

```
  var self = this;
  itemsToDelete.forEach (function(item){
      self.store.deleteRecord(item);
  });
```

When run, some children records would get deleted; others would trigger an error saying: "Cannot call method 'deleteRecord' of undefined."  But if I run the same code over again, some of the children that triggered the error in the previous run would get deleted successfully.  If this code is run multiple times, eventually, all children would be deleted.

There's seems to be some weird timing issue here.  Does anyone know what's going on with this?

Answer (score 0):

The `hasMany` and `belongsTo` names can be somewhat confusing. They make it seem as if Ember-Data is enforcing a hierarchy when it's not. In reality, relationships are just links in Ember-Data and don't implicitly hold any semantic information. So when you delete a record, you're not deleting a record and all of its 'children', you're just deleting that one record. In other words, what you're seeing is expected behavior.

Now on to your problem. I think your main problem is that your server isn't doing enough work. If your data model relies on children being deleted when parents are, that *must* happen on your server. Don't let Ember-Data taint your data model; if those records have no business existing after the parent is gone, your server should make sure to clean up after itself, you shouldn't have to do it manually through ember data. So you having to manually delete records one by one is a big no-no.

That being said, you shouldn't have to worry about unloading the records manually. If you delete the parent, all references to the children should be gone, therefore there should be no way that your application can access them. But, if for some reason you *really* need those records out of the store, you should use the [unload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_unloadRecord) of the store.

TL;DR: Let your server properly delete the records, then the changes will propagate eventually. Don't try to delete them manually.

Comment: When the parent record is deleted via deleteRecord followed by save, a DELETE message is sent, and server deletes both parent and children in the DB. But unless the children records are deleted explicitly on the client, they will linger unless the browser refresh button is pressed (server will send the correct info and reset the store).  Leaving orphaned records in RAM and hope for the best doesn't seem like a good solution.   And depending on browser refresh to do the cleanup seems hackash.  Question is why does my explicit delete attempt works sometimes and fails at other times?

Comment: BTW, 'unload' won't work.  Calling 'unloadAll' would delete all records of a given type, which is not what I want since there are other parents with children of the same record type.  Calling 'unloadRecord' requires instance of the record, which (sometimes - why?) comes back as 'undefined' in my sample code above.

Comment: You'd have to give us more details to figure out why `delete` isn't working correctly. But as far as the lingering records, why do you care? They shouldn't affect anything in your application unless your records are huge (> 1MB) or you're creating and deleting thousands of them in a single session.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer's discussion, if the data already exists on the server side, you should let the server handle the deletion of all child records as opposed to sending a flurry of DELETE requests.

However, to answer your other concern about making sure the ember-data store stays tidy while messing around with the front end, I wrote this block of code that helps to rollback all of the relationships for your model.

```
var model = this.get('model');
var relatedModel, relatedModels;
model.constructor.eachRelationship(function (key, relationship) {
    if (relationship.kind === 'hasMany') {
        relatedModels = model.get(key);
        if (relatedModels) {
            relatedModels.invoke('rollback'); //since this is an array, need to call the rollback function differently
        }
    }
    else {
        relatedModel = model.get(key);
        if (relatedModel) {
            relatedModel.rollback();
        }
    }
});
model.rollback();
```

Comment: Thanks Brad.  But I'm not sure how rollback would help in my situation.  As mentioned in my earlier comments, I do handle record deletion on the server side.  But coming from an old C++ world where the programmer's responsible for memory management, I just don't like to see memory being consumed for no reason.  It's certainly no show stopper to leave the orphaned records in the store, and that's what I think I'll do.  The next page refresh will clean things up automatically.

Comment: If you are creating records in the ember-data store, but later decide you don't need to save those back to the server, I beleive rollback() will delete those from store since they are new records just marked for creation.

Answer (score 0):

I think deleteRecord() not working is caused by a bug in EmberData.  I posted this in the EmberData  issues list.  Please see: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1846.

There's a work around. If I changed code to that shown below, deleteRecord works every single time.

```
   var self = this;
   var realArray = itemsToDelete.toArray();
   realArray.forEach (function(item){
       self.store.deleteRecord(item);
   });
```

Comment: Not a bug after all.  See 'closed' issue 1846 via above link.